# Creating a plugin/package dependency map

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a project in Java with Eclipse. The project uses multi plugins/packages that were written by as and use each other (we import it in the MANIFEST file).
I was wondering if there is a way to get some sort of dependency map, which can shows exactly which plugin imports what. We are trying to dicrease a change of getting a circuit situation (two plugins/packages that use each other).

Is there a way to achieve it somehow?

Comment: Are you using a build system like Maven or Gradle?

Comment: I'm not. We use Ant though.